# Is asp.net webform is opensource compliance

Tags: asp.net, webforms, open-source

My work requires me to do development using full opensource compliance library. I'm about to develop using asp.net webform technology, from research on internet I found that asp.net for MVC , WEB API and RAZOR are open source but nothing mention about the webform.

Does the webform also opensource?

thanks

Comment: WebForm is an anti-patern and it's obsoleted , and as long as it's belong to Asp.Net (not the asp.net core) it's not OpenSource

Comment: As the other comment said you have to use ASP.NET Core. Forget about ASP.NET MVC as though it is open source, the dependency of .NET Framework is not open source.

Comment: @LexLi yeah that confuse me because both are open. Now I got this clear thanks All :)

Comment: If you _really_ need a free and open-source implementation of WebForms, there's Mono.